# Matlab's hist3, which axis corresponds to X and which one to Y

Tags: matlab, histogram

So suppose you pass some matrix `N` to `hist3` in Matlab, which is a `m`-by-`2` matrix, simply for an example purposes. Where the first column is your variable `X` and column `2` corresponds to your variable `Y`.

When you run the `cnt = hist3(N, {bins_X bins_Y})`, you would get a `m`-by-`m` matrix. Rows here are which variable, `X` or `Y`?

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation here [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html?refresh=true) answers all of your questions. 'xlabel' is for the first column of your m-by-2 matrix. and when you run `cnt = hist3(N, {bins_X bins_Y})` it "...returns a matrix containing the number of elements of N that fall in each bin of the grid, and does not plot the histogram."

Comment: I know what it returns, I don't know whether it is the rows that correspond to the axis for X or Y

Comment: The matrix `cnt` that you get contains counts for values in your original matrix within the bins defined by the cross product of bins_X with bins_Y. If you want the frequency of second bin in `x` and third bin in `y` you would call it `cnt(2,3)`. The matrix that you get is basically a grid of your bins in `y` and `x`.

Comment: Yeap, just saw it in my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP seems to have solved his problem. However, I am leaving a code snippet exemplifying hist3's output indexing in case anyone finds it useful.

```
% Simulate random 2-column matrix
X = randn(1e5,2);

% Scale x-axis data to see label distinction
X(:,1) = X(:,1)*10;

% Define bins
bin_x = linspace(-30,30,80);
bin_y = linspace(-3,3,100);

% Get frequency grid
cnt = hist3(X,{bin_x,bin_y});

% Plot frequency values with surf
[x,y] = meshgrid(bin_x,bin_y);
figure
surf(x,y,cnt')
title('Original hist3 output')
xlabel('First Column')
ylabel('Second Column')
zlabel('Frequency')

% Access and modify cnt, and plot again
cnt(end,1:10) = 60;
cnt(25:55,1:55)= 0;
figure
surf(x,y,cnt')
title('Modified hist3 output')
xlabel('First Column')
ylabel('Second Column')
zlabel('Frequency')
```

[image: Original data]

[image]

Comment: OP, feel free to delete the question.